# Prove that there exists an analytic function $g$ such that derivative takes maximum

Tags: complex-analysis

In the complex comp this afternoon, I got stuck in this problem.

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of function mapping $\{z\mid\Re z>0\}$ to itself and $f(1)=1$. Prove that there exists a function $g\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $$|g'''(4)|=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|f'''(4)|.$$

The largest problem is that I have no idea how to use these conditions! I could transform this map to a map from unit disc to itself by Mobius map, but I couldn't derive anything about the third derivative of original function on $4$! I also tried Montel's theorem, but the conditions also seems useless. So I'm wondering how to proceed this problem, any hint or solution is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: You want to apply Montel's theorem. To see that you _can_ apply Montel's theorem, use the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah, just use the Mobius transform $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$, and then use Montel to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family, and thus $\mathcal{F}'''$ is a normal family?

Comment: Right. The uniform boundedness on compact sets comes from Schwarz. What I'd do is once I knew the family of functions in the disk was uniformly bounded on compact sets I'd use that to say that I had similar bounds in the half-plane; then apply Montel _there_. Because it's not entirely clear that a bound on $f''''$ in the disk gives a bound on the function in the half-plane...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks! And when I know the local boundedness, I should apply Montel. And note that the derivative of a normal family is also normal, thus $\mathcal{F}'''$ is normal! It's a pity that I totally missed this this afternoon...